# Unix philosophy - avoid storing data and programs in binary files

Tags: programming, storage, binary

I am unable to understand the reason behind the following Unix philosophy.

From [LINFO Website](http://www.linfo.org/binary_file.html): An important tenet of the Unix philosophy is to avoid storing data and programs in binary files to the extent practical. Rather, they should be stored in plain text files because text is a universal interface among programs and humans. It is the use of text outputs and inputs that allows programs in Unix-like operating systems to work together so easily and efficiently (i.e., through the use of pipes). Although text files might not be as fast (or as small) as binary files, this is easily compensated for by high speeds of modern processors (and the low cost of memory and storage).

Please explain, if possible.

Comment: I don't see a Ubuntu specific question here, thus this reads as off-topic. Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux would be more appropriate for this question.  As to your question: It's hard[er] to 'grep|sed....' binary files for starters so much of ....  (but it's off-topic!)

Comment: @guiverc Just to add to what you already said. Binary files are harder to `grep` because `grep` is a line-matching tool, which means there has to be a sequence of bytes in binary file that matches `\n` character, but binary files may or may not have that sequence of bytes.

Comment: @guiverc Is it possible to shift this question to Unix and Linux StackExchange?

Comment: @Nikhil Questions closed as off-topic can be moved to U&L site. I can put in another vote to close it here and later a moderator can move it. Just let me know if you'd like that.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for your consideration. I apologize for posting the question in the wrong community. I hope that I am not banned from the community.

Comment: @Nikhil No, you won't be banned, and no need to apologize - happens to the best of us. There is however automatic ban if your account has a certain history of poor posts, which is explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295160   As for this question, it does suit more towards U&L site, but my personal opinion is that since Ubuntu is Unix-like system and shares its philosophy, it totally belongs here. There's a lot of gray areas on what belongs on this site, and lots of confusion,too.  But that's just my opinion; community decides.

Comment: @Nikhil you won't be banned, no, but I will state that this question you posted as is does not meet the quality standards necessary for migration.  Feel free to post the question yourself on Unix and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question shortly, the article you cite is kinda wrong. Unix philosophy is that everything is a file, but it doesn't mean *text* file. A particular example of that would be sockets. See for instance [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116616) here: socket is a file, but that doesn't necessarily mean it has filename and doesn't have to exist on hard drive, and data passed via sockets isn't necessarily text but particular byte sequences.

Pipes themselves, in particular anonymous pipes as in `|`, can themselves be files without existing on disk. Data passed via pipes can be of any type - binary or text. One example of that would be piping compressed archive of iso image to `dd` command to write it to disk.

Among other things, it's also not necessarily true that text files can be slower than binary files. If program that you use to read text file takes (proper) advantage of [mmap()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) system call, that maps file completely or partially to RAM, and as you know RAM is fast. Ever wondered why `tail` can be very very fast at getting last few lines of a file that is gigabytes large ? Well, if you run `strace` system call analyzer on `tail`, it will show you that there's  `mmap()` syscalls happening.

Speed of processors is also kinda irrelevant here and all benefits of having multi-core processors can go to nill if program that you use to read a file with is written  as sequential program (not as parallel program, hence can't make any use of multiple cores) or there's [memory wall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall) where width of memory bus/speed of memory can't support CPU's speed.

Regarding this:

> Rather, they should be stored in plain text files because text is a universal interface among programs and humans.

Yes, text can be convenient for communicating between a machine and human, but in case of security there's a reason why we would want to store data in encrypted binary form where to an attacker data would look only as sequence of bytes, an unreadable mess.